# SQL Server : Create Timetable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that records the start and end of a day schedule:

```
ScheduleID  VenueID Date        StartTime EndTime
    1          1    14/07/2013   10:30     16:30
    2          1    15/07/2013   09:30     16:30
    3          2    16/07/2013   09:00     16:00
```

I need to create a table that self populates 30 minute time slots based in the start and end time so it looks something like this:

```
TimetableID VenueID    Date      Time_Slots  Client1ID    Client2ID
     1        1     14/07/2013     10:30        45           Null
     2        1     14/07/2013     11:00        67           78
     3        1     14/07/2013     11:30        104          Null
     4        1     14/07/2013     12:00        112          56
```

etc

Any help on how I generate the second table so that I can simple add the Client1ID and Clinet2ID would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Tim, I need to have a table on my front end platform that lets the user see the available slots for the whole day. They can book in 2 clients per 30 minutes session.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean be `'self populating table'` and you don't say where the `clientid`'s come from (so i'll leave that to you). But you can get a result set of 30 minute time slots with something like this

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT id, venue, schedule_date, 
         start_time time_slots, end_time
  FROM schedule
  UNION ALL
  SELECT schedule.id, schedule.venue, schedule.schedule_date, 
         DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, cte.time_slots) time_slots, 
         schedule.end_time
  FROM schedule
  INNER JOIN cte
          ON cte.id = schedule.id
         AND cte.time_slots < schedule.end_time
)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id, time_slots),
       venue,
       schedule_date,
       time_slots
FROM cte
ORDER BY id, time_slots
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d16c4/8)